Prove that the sequence defined by $a_{n + 1} = 2a_n^2 - 1$ is always negative iff $a_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$
I want to prove that the sequence defined by $a_{n + 1} = 2(a_n)^2 - 1$ is always negative if and only if $a_1 = -\dfrac{1}{2}$.
Here are some observations I've made so far. However, I haven't been able to consolidate them into a full proof:

With $a_1 = -\dfrac{1}{2}$, all terms in the sequence are $-\dfrac{1}{2}$. So, $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ is a fixed point of the sequence. The only other fixed point of the sequence (found by solving the equation $a_n = a_{n + 1} \iff a_n = 2(a_n)^2 - 1$) is $1$, but that is not negative.
Now, say that $a_n \leq 0$. If $(a_n)^2 > \dfrac{1}{2}$ (iff $a_n < \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$), then we are guaranteed that $a_{n + 1} > 0$, and we are done. Otherwise, if $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \leq a_n \leq 0$, we have $-\dfrac{1}{2} \leq a_{n + 1} \leq 1$, and so $\dfrac{1}{4} \leq (a_{n + 1})^2 \leq 1$, and so $-\dfrac{1}{2} \leq a_{n + 2} \leq 1$. This is the same constraint we found on $a_{n + 1}$, so continuing this way gives us no progress.
Finally, I've observed that when I test different values for $a_1$, the values seem to oscillate around $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ (getting farther away every time, unless we started at $-\dfrac{1}{2}$) until we find a value whose square is more than $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I'm not sure what this implies, though.

Can anyone provide hints or a solution to this problem?

@c'estpasnormale So far, my thoughts are that if we let $a_0 = \cos{\theta_0}$, we must have $\pi/2 < \theta_0 < 3\pi/2$ in order for $a_0 < 0$. Then, in order for $\cos{2\theta_0}$ to be negative, we must have $\pi/2 < \theta_0 < 3\pi/4$ or $5\pi/4 < \theta_0 < \pi$. Do I just proceed by finding the intersection of these infinitely-many intervals?

Have you studied $f(x)=2x^2-1$ and $g(x)=f(x)-x$ ? Variations, behaviour, roots, in order to know the behaviour of your sequence depending on where your start (make a variation table for each function. (Track beginning and hint : -$1/2$ is a root of $g$)

Let $a_n=\cos\theta_n$. Then, $a_{n+1}=2a_n^2-1=2\cos^2\theta_n-1=\cos2\theta_n=\cos\left(2^n\theta_1\right)$ since $\theta_n=\frac12\arccos(2a_n^2-1)=\frac12\arccos\left(2\cos^22\theta_{n-1}-1\right)=\frac12\arccos\left(\cos4\theta_{n-1}\right)=2\theta_{n-1}=2^2\theta_{n-2}=2^{n-1}\theta_1.$
We have to find $a_1=\cos\theta_1<0$ such that $a_n=\cos\left(2^{n-1}\theta_1\right)<0$ or $a_{n+1}=\cos\left(2^n\theta_1\right)<0,~~\forall n\in\mathbb N$.
We know that $\cos\theta_1<0$ if $\frac\pi2<\theta_1<\frac{3\pi}2$ (2nd and 3rd quadrants).
For $a_{n+1}=\cos\left(2^n\theta_1\right)<0$, $(2^n\theta_1)$ must fall in either the 2nd or 3rd quadrants for all $n\in\mathbb N$, i.e., there exists an integer $m$ such that $2m\pi+\frac\pi2<2^n\theta_1<2m\pi+\frac{3\pi}2$. Geometrically, it is easy to visualize that it is possible if and only if $\theta_1=\frac{2\pi}3~\mathrm{rad}=120^\circ$ or $\frac{4\pi}3~\mathrm{rad}=240^\circ$, i.e., $a_1=\cos\theta_1=-\frac12$. This is because it is the only angle that repeats the angles of $\frac{2\pi}3$ or $\frac{4\pi}3$ in $\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$ when we keep doubling it. The intuition is that we must divide $2\pi$ into $3$ equal parts for the repetition as both $\theta_1$ and $2\theta_1$ must lie in either the 2nd or 3rd quadrants. To see why that is not possible with other angles, let $\theta_1=\frac{2\pi}3\pm\epsilon\in\left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}4\right)$. When we keep doubling $\theta_1$, the gap $\epsilon~($with $\theta=\frac{2\pi}3$ or $\frac{4\pi}3)$ also gets doubled each time, leading to falling of $(2^n\theta_1)$ outside of the 2nd and 3rd quadrants. This means that $a_n$ will not always have negative values. So, only $\theta_1=\frac{2\pi}3$ or $\frac{4\pi}3$ ensures that $a_n$ is always negative.
Hence, the sequence defined by $a_{n+1}=2a_n^2-1$ is always negative iff $a_1=-\frac12$. $\blacksquare$


This is not an answer but a track to study your problem with graphic and foster study of function as precised in the comment.
Starting at $-1$

Starting at $\sqrt{2}$

Starting at $-\sqrt{2}$

Starting at $1/3$

Starting at $a_1=-1/2$, note it stands at the intersection of the curve of $f$ and the $y=x$ curve

Starting at $a_1=1$, note it also stands at the intersection of the curve of $f$ and the $y=x$ curve but here positively

Finally
Note that $1$ and $-1/2$, are the roots of $f-\text{Id}$, with $f$ is such that :
$$ f(a_n)=a_{n+1} $$
Studying $f$ and $g=f-\text{Id}$ especially the variation and the stability of certain intervals by $f$ (intervals defined especially by the roots of $f$ and $g$)
For the beginning
Studying $f$ and $g$
For f
$$f(x)=2x^2-1=(x\pm \sqrt{2})$$
$$f'(x)=4x $$
So
$$ f'(x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=0 $$
$$ f \ \text{is thus decreasing then increasing with minimum in $x$=0} $$
Noting that :
$$f(0)=-1$$
$$f(\pm \sqrt{2})=0$$
For g
$$g(x)=2x^2-1-x=(x-1)(x+1/2)$$
$$g'(x)=4x-1 $$
So
$$ g'(x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=1/4 $$
$$ g \ \text{is thus decreasing then increasing with minimum in $x$=1/4} $$
Noting that :
$$g(0)=-1$$
$$g(1)=0=f(-1/2)$$
Now:
$$f(a_n)=a_{n+1}$$
$$g(a_n)=a_{n+1}-a_n $$

Another use for cobweb diagrams here is to use the bijection $\theta\in [0,\pi]\leftrightarrow a=\cos\theta\in[-1,1]$ to recast the iteration as $\theta_{n+1}=\pi-|\pi-2\theta_n|$. A few iterations then make clear that $\theta=2\pi/3$ is a unstable fixed point and thus the iteration always reaches positive $\cos\theta$

Note that if $~a_n \leq -1,~$ or $~a_n \geq 0,~$ then you are done.
Note further that $~\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1.$
So, start with $~\pi/2 < \theta < \pi ~: \theta \neq \dfrac{2\pi}{3},$ 
with $~a_1 = \cos(\theta).$
Then, the sequence $~a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots~$ is given by 
$\cos(\theta), ~\cos(2\theta), ~\cos(4\theta), \cdots.$
Note that $~\theta = (2\pi/3)~$ will generate the sequence
$$\cos(2\pi/3), ~\cos(4\pi/3), ~\cos(2\pi/3), ~\cos(4\pi/3) ~\cdots.$$
What is desired is that for any other $~\theta~$ such that $~\pi/2 < \theta < \pi,~$ you have to find an $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that
$$2^n \times \theta \equiv \alpha \pmod{2\pi} ~: -\pi/2 \leq \alpha \leq \pi/2. \tag1 $$

$~\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~\theta = 2\pi/3 + \beta ~: 0 < \beta < \pi/12}$
From (1) above, it is sufficient to find an $~\alpha~$ such that
$$2^n \times \theta \equiv \alpha \pmod{2\pi} ~: 3\pi/4 \leq \alpha \leq 5\pi/4.$$
This explains why you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~\beta < \pi/12.$
Starting with the constraint that $~0 < \beta < \pi/12$:
Then within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~4\theta = 2\pi/3 + 4\beta.$
Similarly, within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~16\theta = 2\pi/3 + 16\beta.$
Similarly, within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~64\theta = 2\pi/3 + 64\beta.$
So, what is needed is to find $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that
$\pi/12 \leq ~4^n \beta \leq 7\pi/12.$
That is, if such an $~n~$ is found, then you will have $~3\pi/4 \leq 4^n\theta \leq 5\pi/4,~$ within a modulus of $~2\pi.~$ This will then imply that $~6\pi/4 \leq 2^{2n+1}\theta \leq 10\pi/4,~$ which implies that you are done.
Let $~N~$ denote the largest non-negative integer such that $~4^N\beta < \pi/12.$
Then, $~4^{N+1}\beta \geq \pi/12~$ and $~4^{N+1}\beta < 4\pi/12 \leq 7\pi/12.$
So, the necessary positive integer $~(N+1)~$ must exist.
Therefore, Case 1 is completely resolved.

$~\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~\theta = 2\pi/3 - \beta ~: 0 < \beta < \pi/6}$
The analysis here will be very similar to that of Case 1.
That is, within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~4\theta = 2\pi/3 - 4\beta.$
Similarly, within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~16\theta = 2\pi/3 - 16\beta.$
Similarly, within a $~\pmod{2\pi}~$ congruence, $~64\theta = 2\pi/3 - 64\beta.$
So, what is needed is to find $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that
$\pi/6 \leq ~4^n \beta \leq 4\pi/6.$
Let $~N~$ denote the largest non-negative integer such that $0 < ~4^N\beta < \pi/6.~$
Then $~\pi/6 \leq 4^{N+1}\beta \leq 4\pi/6,~$ and you are done with Case 2.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
In the comments following this answer, there is an interesting analytical discussion between me and Semiclassical.  I am generally ignorant of math problems in this genre, so I can well believe that with slightly different problems, it becomes important to create a map that has each of $~\theta_1, ~\theta_2,  ~\theta_3, ~\cdots \in [ ~0, \pi ~],~$ within a modulus of $~2\pi.$
In this particular problem, that is irrelevant.  The only thing that counts is that if (for example) $~a_1 = \cos(2\pi/3 + \beta),~$ that the subsequence $~a_3, ~a_5, ~a_7, \cdots ~$ is then accurately represented by $~\cos(2\pi/3 + 4\beta), ~\cos(2\pi/3 + 16\beta), ~\cos(2\pi/3 + 64\beta), \cdots, ~$ without any regard for whether $~(2\pi/3 + 4^n\beta)~$ is (within a modulus of $~2\pi)~$ an element in $~[ ~0,\pi ~].$

While I think using $a_{n+1}=\cos 2\theta_n$ is the right idea, I don't think the proper iteration here is $\theta_{n+1}=2\theta_n$. Rather, it should be the tent map: For $\theta\in [0,\pi]$, $\theta_{n+1}=f(\theta_n)$ where $f(\theta)=\pi-|\pi-2\theta|$. This in particular has $f(2\pi/3)=2\pi/3$, so that this is also a fixed point of the iteration.

@Semiclassical I am confused by your comment, so let's go back to basics, first, and then I will discuss your comment further.  The first issue is: did you find an analytical mistake in my answer?  If so, please explicitly point it out.

To go from $a_{n+1}=\cos(\theta_{n+1})=\cos(2\theta_n)$ to $\theta_{n+1}=2\theta_n$, you've implicitly used inverse cosine. But the codomain of inverse cosine is $[0,\pi]$, so $\theta\to 2\theta$ cannot be valid for all $\theta$. In particular, suppose that $\theta_n=\pi-\epsilon$ for some small positive $\epsilon$. Then $\cos(2\theta_n)=\cos(2\pi-2\epsilon)=\cos(2\epsilon)$, so one should have $\pi-\epsilon\to 2\epsilon$ not $2(\pi-\epsilon)$. That's precisely what $\theta\to \pi-|\pi-2\theta|$ achieves.

@Semiclassical I am going to have to disagree with your assertion that my analysis in any way depends on the arccosine function.  Suppose (for example) that $~a_1 = \cos(2\pi/3 + 1/100).~$  Then, the subsequence $~a_3, a_5, a_7, \cdots,~$ is accurately represented by $~\cos(2\pi/3 + 4/100), ~\cos(2\pi/3 + 8/100), ~\cos(2\pi/3 + 16/100), ~\cdots $ without any regard for whether any of the arclengths (within a modulus of $~2\pi),~$ are outside of the range $~0 \leq \text{arclength} \leq \pi,~$ within a modulus of $~2\pi.~$That is totally irrelevant.  ...see next comment

@Semiclassical The only thing that counts is that since the subsequence $~a_3, a_5, a_7~$ is being accurately represented, and since you must eventually have an arclength within the range $~[-\pi \leq \text{arclength} \leq \pi]~$ (within a modulus of $~2\pi),~$ then you must eventually have an element $~a_{2k+1}~$ that is positive.

@Semiclassical Correction to my I am going to have to disagree comment - should be: the subsequence $~a_3, a_5, a_7, \cdots,~$ is accurately represented by $~\cos(2\pi/3 + 4/100),  ~\cos(2\pi/3 + 16/100), ~ \cos(2\pi/3 + 64/100), ~\cdots.$  Also, correction to my previous comment: ... then you must eventually have an element $~a_k~$ that is non-negative.

Upon reflection, I will concede that in this context the doubling map suffices. I still prefer the tent map, mostly because it has the same kinds of orbits as the original quadratic map (e.g.,, the unstable fixed point $a=-1/2$ of $a\mapsto 2a^2-1$ goes over to $\theta=2\pi/3$ as an unstable fixed point of $\theta\mapsto \pi-|2\theta-\pi|$). But in the present context that's not necessary.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sketch of proof.
The recurrence is $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}^2-1$ and we want $a_k\leq 0$ for all $k$.
Solving $a_{n+1}\leq 0$ for $a_n$ and recalling $a_n\leq 0$ gives $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq 0.$
Solving  $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq 0$ for $a_{n-1}$ and recalling $a_{n-1}\leq 0$ gives $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n-1}\leq -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}.$
Solving $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n-1}\leq -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}$ for $a_{n-2}$ and recalling $a_{n-2}\leq0$ gives
$-\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}\leq a_{n-2}\leq -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}{2}.$
Solving $-\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}\leq a_{n-2}\leq -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}{2}$ for $a_{n-3}$ and recalling $a_{n-3}\leq0$ gives
$-\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\leq a_{n-3}\leq -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}}}}{2}.$
Continuing in this manner (and letting $n\to\infty$) it follows that $\frac{x}{2}\leq a_{1} \leq \frac{x}{2}$ where $x=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2-\cdots}}.$
Notice $x=-\sqrt{2+x}.$ So $x$ is the negative root of $x^2=2+x$, this equation has roots $2$ and $-1$. Consequently, $x=-1$ which gives the desired result.

We do the normalization $b_n:=-2a_n$, then $b_n$ satisfies the recursive relation
$$b_{n+1}=2-b_n^2$$
Now we show $b_n>0$ for all $n$ iff $b_1 = 1$. It's easy to see that if $b_i=1$ for some $i$, then $b_{i+1}=b_{i+2}=\cdots = 1$ and $b_{i-1}=1$ is also the only positive solution of $1=2-x^2$, thus $b_n\equiv 1$. WLOG, we may assume $b_n\not=1$ for all $n$. Assume also $b_n>0$ for all $n$, and we'll demonstrate a contradiction.
Note that $|b_{n+1}-1|=|1-b_n||1+b_n|>|b_n-1|$, therefore $|b_n-1|$ is increasing and bounded above as $0<b_n=2-b_{n-1}^2<2$. So it converges to some $b>|b_0-1|>0$. Therefore $1+b_n = \big|\frac{b_{n+1}-1}{b_n-1}\big|\rightarrow 1$ and $b_n\rightarrow 0$, but then take $n\rightarrow\infty$ on both sides of $b_{n+1}=2-b_n^2$, we end up with $0=2$.

This assumes familiarity with Newton-Raphson. Consider $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2x+1}{1-x}}$. If you apply Newton-Raphson to this function, you end up with the recursion
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}
&=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}\\
\ldots&\text{simplify}\ldots\\
a_{n+1}&=2a_n^2-1
\end{align}$$
So your recurrence relation would agree with Newton-Rhapson on $f$. Now look at $f$:

No matter where you start with $a_1$ on the $x$-axis (excluding $-1/2$ and $1$) you can follow the tangent lines a la Newton-Raphson, and see that you will eventually land at a positive $x$-values after enough iterations. Here's an illustration of a case where you need three iterations:

If you start near $-1/2$, then it may take many iterations. (The cube root behavior near $-1/2$ famously leads to Newton-Raphson diverging, with each iteration bringing you twice as far from the root as you previously were.)
Of course at $-1/2$ and $1$ you cannot apply Newton-Raphson, but the original sequence is constant.

Turned my sketch in a previous answer into a proof.
Consider the recurrence is $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}^{2}-1$ for all $n\geq1.$
Assuming $a_{k}\leq0$ for all $k\geq1.$ We will show $a_{1}=-\tfrac{1}{2}.$
$\mathbf{Fact \, 1}$: If $0\leq b<a\leq1,x\leq0$ and $-\tfrac{a}{2}\leq2x^{2}-1\leq-\tfrac{b}{2},$
then $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-b}}{2}\leq x\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-a}}{2}.$
$\mathbf{Fact \, 2}$: If $n\geq1,$ $0\leq b<a\leq1,$ and $-\tfrac{a}{2}\leq a_{n+2}\leq-\tfrac{b}{2},$
then $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-a}}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-b}}}{2}.$
Let $c_{0}=0$ and $c_{k+1}=\sqrt{2-c_{k}},$ for $k\geq0.$
$\mathbf{Fact \, 3}$: For $n\geq1.$ If $n$ is odd, then $-\tfrac{c_{n}}{2}\leq a_{1}\leq-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}.$
If $n$ is even, then $-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}\leq a_{1}\leq-\tfrac{c_{n}}{2}.$
$\mathbf{Fact \, 4}$: $c_{n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty.$
The desired result follows immediately from Fact 3 and Fact 4. Actually,
we only need the $n$ odd case of Fact 3, so the proof could be shortened
slightly.
$\mathbf{Proof \, of \, Fact \, 1}$: Since $-\tfrac{a}{2}\leq2x^{2}-1\leq-\tfrac{b}{2},$
then $\tfrac{2-a}{4}\leq x^{2}\leq\tfrac{2-b}{4}$ so either $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-b}}{2}\leq x\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-a}}{2}$
or $\tfrac{\sqrt{2-a}}{2}\leq x\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2-b}}{2}.$ Since
$x\leq0$ only the first case is applicable.
$\mathbf{Proof \, of \, Fact \, 2}$: Since $-\tfrac{a}{2}\leq a_{n+2}\leq-\tfrac{b}{2},$
then $-\tfrac{a}{2}\leq2a_{n+1}^{2}-1\leq-\tfrac{b}{2},$ so $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-b}}{2}\leq a_{n+1}\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-a}}{2},$
by Fact 1. Hence, $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-b}}{2}\leq2a_{n}^{2}-1\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-a}}{2},$
so by Fact 1 $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-a}}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq-\tfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-b}}}{2}.$
$\mathbf{Proof \, of \, Fact \, 3}$: Since $a_{n+1}\leq0,$ we have $2a_{n}^{2}-1\leq0$
hence $-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$ Using
$a_{n}\leq0$ gives $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq0.$ That is
$-\tfrac{c_{1}}{2}\leq a_{n}\leq-\tfrac{c_{0}}{2}.$ By Fact 2 (and
an easy induction argument) we have $-\tfrac{c_{1+2k}}{2}\leq a_{n-2k}\leq-\tfrac{c_{2k}}{2}$
for all $k,$ such that $n-2k\geq1.$
If $n$ is odd, pick $k$ such that $n-2k=1$ and conclude $-\tfrac{c_{n}}{2}\leq a_{1}\leq-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}.$
If $n$ is even, pick $k$ such that $n-2k=2$ and conclude $-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}\leq a_{2}\leq-\tfrac{c_{n-2}}{2}.$
Hence $-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}\leq2a_{1}^{2}-1\leq-\tfrac{c_{n-2}}{2},$
so Fact 1 gives $-\tfrac{c_{n-1}}{2}\leq a_{1}\leq-\tfrac{c_{n}}{2}.$
$\mathbf{Proof \, of \, Fact \, 4}$: Clearly, $0<c_{k}\leq\sqrt{2}$ for all $k\geq0.$
Let $g\left(t\right)=\sqrt{2-t},$ then $g'\left(t\right)=-\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2-t}}.$
For $0\leq t\leq\sqrt{2}$ we have $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\leq\sqrt{2-t},$
so $\left|g'\left(t\right)\right|=\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2-t}}\leq\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}<\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$
The inequality used $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}>\sqrt{2-1.5}=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$
Hence the Mean Value Theorem yields $\left|g\left(t\right)-g\left(s\right)\right|\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left|t-s\right|$
for $0\leq s,t\leq\sqrt{2}.$ Therefore,
$$
\left|c_{k+2}-c_{k+1}\right|=\left|g\left(c_{k+1}\right)-g\left(c_{k}\right)\right|\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left|c_{k+1}-c_{k}\right|
$$
for all $k\geq1.$ A Standard Argument (repeated below) now shows
the sequence $c_{n}$ is Cauchy and therefore convergent. Let $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}c_{n}.$
Since $0\leq c_{n}\leq\sqrt{2}$ also $0\leq x\leq\sqrt{2}.$ Since
$g(x)=\sqrt{2-x}$ is continuous, taking the limit of $c_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-c_{n}}$
as $n\to\infty$ yields $x=\sqrt{2-x},$ so $x^{2}=2-x.$ This quadratic
has roots $1$ and $-2.$ Since $x\geq0,$ it follows that $x=1.$
$\mathbf{The \, Standard \, Argument}$: Iterating $\left|c_{k+2}-c_{k+1}\right|\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left|c_{k+1}-c_{k}\right|$
shows
$$
\left|c_{n+1}-c_{n}\right|\leq\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left|c_{n}-c_{n-1}\right|\leq\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{2}\left|c_{n-1}-c_{n-2}\right|\leq\cdots\leq\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n}\left|c_{1}-c_{0}\right|=\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2}.
$$
So, if $m>n,$ then
\begin{align*}
\left|c_{n}-c_{m}\right| & \leq\left|c_{n}-c_{n+1}\right|+\left|c_{n+2}-c_{n+3}\right|+\cdots+\left|c_{m-1}-c_{m}\right|.\\
 & \leq\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2}+\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{m-1}\sqrt{2}\\
 & \leq\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{k}\\
 & =\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2}\tfrac{2}{2-\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}
Hence the sequence $c_{n}$ is Cauchy.
